# execute python script direct from C# without using process and cmd

Tags: python, c#

I'm new in Python and I have the below Python script and want to run it direct from C# without using process and cmd tried many ways but I didn't reach a solution, may someone help me with the steps and the code to do it i saw Pythonnet but I'm not able to find the right code

script :

```
from easyocr import Reader
import cv2
import os
import sys
import pyodbc

def corrupt_msg():
return "The file is corrupted."

def arabic_to_english_numerals(text):
arabic_numerals = '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'
english_numerals = '0123456789'
for i in range(len(arabic_numerals)):
text = text.replace(arabic_numerals[i], english_numerals[i])
return text
def is_arabic_numerals(text):
arabic_numerals = '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'
for char in text:
if char not in arabic_numerals:
return False
return True
def is_English_numerals(text):
eng_numerals = '0123456789'
for char in text:
if char not in eng_numerals:
return False
return True
def DBInsert(imgename,BJRN,results):
# Define the connection parameters
server = '.\SQLSERVER19'
database = 'BAB_ErrorLog'
username = 'sa'
password = 'P@ssw0rd'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

# Connect to the database
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}')
#conn = pyodbc.connect(f'SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}')

# Create a table
cursor = conn.cursor()
#cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), age INT)')

# Insert a row of data
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tblBJRN (Imgname, BJRN,Results) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (imgename, BJRN,results))

# Commit the transaction and close the connection
cursor.commit()
conn.close()
def OCRimg(directory, imagename):

IMAGE_PATH = directory + '\\' + imagename
name_without_extension = os.path.splitext(imagename)[0]
image = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
#image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)
#image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
languages = ['en', 'ar']
reader = Reader(languages, gpu=False)
results =reader.readtext(image, detail=0,allowlist=['٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩','B','J','R','N','M'])
BJRN = None
print(imagename)
words=[]
for i in results:     

    i = i.replace("٥JRN", "")  
    i = i.replace("B", "")
    i = i.replace("J", "")
    i = i.replace("R", "")
    i = i.replace("N", "")
    i = i.replace("M", "")
    i = i.replace("٢٠٠٥", "")
    i = i.replace("٢٠٠٤", "")
    i = i.replace("'", "")
    words.append(arabic_to_english_numerals(i))
    if len(i) == 6 and is_arabic_numerals(i):
        BJRN = arabic_to_english_numerals("\u202b" + i + "\u202c")
with open(directory + '\\'+name_without_extension+'.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        print(str(words), file=f)
folder_path =sys.argv[1]
file=sys.argv[2]
OCRvalue = OCRimg(folder_path,file)`
```

I tried using ironpython but is giving eeror , No module easyOCR
have many trils with python.runtime without any output

I want to run the python code directly from C# wthout using a call a process and strat it.

Comment: The indentation of your code is wrong.  Indentation matters very much in Python, so you'll need to fix that.  IronPython is a good solution, but you will need to install the add-on packages this needs (easyocr, OpenCV2, pyodbc), and I don't know if those are available for IronPython.  It may be running it as a separate process is the easiest method.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply the indentation is not an issue I believe this happened here because of the copy and paste from the original code, for IronPython, I tried to use it but I faced issues  related to the versions and compatibility